# Magento not sending any email (eg,order,invoice,send email)

Tags: email, magento-1.9

I am using Magento 1.9.0.1 and using SMTP Pro Magento SMTP Email free extension I have configured it in right way before days ago my email was working good. But now after creating new order, invoice and after opening a order detail page and click on send email tab it's giving the message `The message has been sent.` and also after order opening it's showing message `the invoice email was sent`. Can anybody tell me why this happening?

I have tried the bellow things at my end.

1) I have checked all back-end settings.

2) Disabled extensions.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.

For me, it was the problem, that I had an own module overriding the Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template Class (send method).

Instead I had to override the Aschroeder_SMTPPro_Model_Email_Template Class and use its send method for my modifications, not the code of the send method of the core class.

Maybe you're having a similar issue or it may lead you to the bug?